# Updating the view with $interval

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a simple Pomodoro timer, and still in the early stages of learning Angular. I'm having trouble updating the view every second with the $scope.timeView variable. $scope.timeView logs to the console every second, but not the view. I have tried injecting $interval and using apply(), but their not working. I'm sure its something obvious to a trained eye, I'll keep searching. In the meantime any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
  pomodoro_timer.controller('app.controller', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {

  // (function() {
  var intrvl;
  var t = 1500;
  var tDiv = $('#time');


  $scope.startTimer = function() {
    if (tDiv.hasClass("notWorking")) {
      $scope.interval(t);
      $scope.toggleClass();
    }
  };

  $scope.interval = function() {
    intrvl = setInterval(function(){
    t -= 1;
    $scope.displayTime(t)
    },1000)
  }

  $scope.displayTime = function() {
    var m = parseInt(t / 60);
    var s = parseInt(t) % 60;

    if (s < 10) {
      s = "0" + s;
    }
     $scope.timeView = m+":"+s;
  }

  $scope.stopStart = function() {
    if (tDiv.hasClass('working')) {
      $scope.toggleClass();
      clearInterval(intrvl);
      $('#QwkBreak a').text('Continue Working');        //////////////////////Should I remove jQuery?/////////////////////////
    } else if (t<1500) {          // prevents timer from starting when '#QwkBreak' is clicked, unless timer has started counting down //
      $('#QwkBreak a').text('Quick Break');
      $scope.interval();
      $scope.toggleClass();
    }
  }

  $scope.toggleClass = function() {
    tDiv.toggleClass('notWorking working');
  }

   $scope.resetTimer = function() {
    if (!tDiv.hasClass('notWorking')) {         //prevents reset button from toggling classes unless (class="working") //
      clearInterval(intrvl);
      t = 1500;
      tDiv.text("25:00");
      $scope.toggleClass();
    }
  }

// })();s
}]);




<body ng-controller="app.controller">
  <h1>Pomodoro Timer</h1>
  <div id="timeView">
    <p id="time" class="notWorking">{{ timeView }}</p>
  </div>
    <div id="controls">
      <button id="startWork"><a ng-click="startTimer()" href="#">Start Work</a></button>
      <button id="QwkBreak"><a ng-click="stopStart()" href="#">Quick Break</a></button>
      <button id="reset"><a ng-click="resetTimer()" href="#">Reset</a></button>
      <button id="5_MInBreak">5-Min Break</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't do DOM manipulation in a controller. The CSS class should come from the model. And do use $interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has `$interval` service that internally will manage digests and also allows for easily getting rid of timers using `cancel()` method

```
$scope.interval = function() {
    intrvl = $interval(function(){
    t -= 1;
    $scope.displayTime(t)
    },1000)
  }
```

Now you also want to remove that interval timer from the window when scope is destroyed

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    intrvl.cancel();
});
```

you will need to inject `$interval` in controller also

Also suggest that all of this timer related code should be placed in a directive. Controllers should not have any dom related code in them

Reference: [$interval docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$interval)

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond. Thanks, it worked. I ended up stopping the interval like so:(_$interval.cancel($scope.intrvl);_). How does this differ from your suggestion?